# Triggering a panel overlay when hovering when the panel overlay has pointer-events:none applied?

Tags: html, css

In the inlined demo when hovering over the `div` with the `PanelOverlay` class on it, it should trigger the `PanelOverlay:hover`  rule, however the `PanelOverlay` class has `pointer-events:none` specified in it and this causes the `hover` not to trigger and so the square does not turn black.

The idea is to indicate that the user is hovering over the item by using a color like `rgba(255,255,255, 0.3)`, however the panel should still allow click through events.  In other words it should behave like a button that is highlighted when hovered.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 64px;
}
.IconContainer {
  background-color: white;
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}

.IconContainer.OnActive:hover span {
  color: black;
  transition: 1s;
}

.PanelOverlay {
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.PanelOverlay:hover {
  z-index: 20000;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
    <main style="position: relative; display: flex; width: 64px">
      <div class="IconContainer OnActive">
        <span class="material-icons-outlined">home</span>
      </div>
      <div class="PanelOverlay"></div>
    </main>
```

This is a Stackblitz containing the same demo.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-dtxtv2?file=styles.css,index.html

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: `pointer-events: none;` I'm assuming that's the root of your problem.

Comment: @disinfor It's not, as preventing pointer events on the `.PanelOverlay` does not prevent them being emmitted on the `.IconContainer` .

Comment: @JohannesH. It would still prevent it from triggering the `PanelOverlay:hover` when `PanelOverlay` has `pointer-events: none`, though.

Comment: @disinfor You are right.  When I remove `pointer-events:none` it works ...

Comment: @Ole glad that was the solution for you!

Comment: @somethinghere You're absolutely correct and I looked ad the completely wrong part of it. I totally missed the second hover and was assuming it was about the IconCOntainer all along. I stand corrected.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is trigger the panel overlay when the user hovers, however it has to have `pointer-events` none in order to be able to trigger and click what is beneath the panel as well.  Anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Thanks guys!!  I updated the question to be more inline with what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @Ole I wrote up an answer, but it may not achieve exactly what you're looking for. Should the`PanelOverlay` cover the `IconContainer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `::before` pseudo element and trigger it on `hover` as shown below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 64px;
}

.IconContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.IconContainer::before {
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  transition: 1s;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.IconContainer.OnActive:hover {
  color: black;
}

.IconContainer.OnActive:hover::before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="IconContainer OnActive">
    <span class="material-icons-outlined">home</span>
  </div>
  <div class="PanelOverlay"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: disinfor that's really cool!  I like the effect.  It's just that I would like the square only to change on hover.  Here's a Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-twvebq?file=styles.css,index.html

Comment: @Ole - I updated my answer but changed the styling a bit. I looked at the stackblitz and it looks like the `PanelOverlay` should only affect the button itself, so I used a pseudo element instead for the overlay element. I could be off-base of what you're trying to do.

Comment: disinfor brilliant that's what I was going for - THANKS!!!  After I saw your example I realized that it can also be achieved by moving the `:hover` selector to the parent element like this:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-wryyoe?file=styles.css,index.html

Comment: @Ole right on! From your example, I would recommend that you put the `transition` property on the default state, instead of the `:hover`, it makes it smooth after the mouse exits, unless that quick off is what you're going for.

Comment: Sweet - will do!!  Thanks for the tip!!